# Get daily close values of the last N days, regardless of chart's timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I'm not able to figure out how to grab the last 200-days of close values, for example.

I believe the core issue is that the `security` function returns a series indexed by the chart's current timeframe, and not by the resolution itself. I cannot find any option to alter this behavior.

Eg:

```
sec = security("SPY", "D", close)
// this will return the close 100 bars ago, not days ago!
sec[100]
```

In this example, I'm trying to plot the 10-day moving average, regardless of the chart's timeframe:

```
//@version=4
study(title='Test', overlay=false, max_labels_count=500) 

// get the daily close for asset and benchmark
sec = security("SPY", "D", close)
lookback = 10

get_daily_closes(sec, lookback) =>
    // populate array with "lookback" number of values
    // unfortunatley, sec[i] will not be the value i days ago, but the value i bars ago.
    var arr_daily_closes = array.new_float()
    array.clear(arr_daily_closes)
    for i = 0 to lookback-1
        array.push(arr_daily_closes, sec[i])
    arr_daily_closes
    
get_arr_avg(arr) =>
    // compute the average of the entire array
    var float sum = 0.0
    sum := 0
    var length = array.size(arr)
    for i = 0 to length-1
        sum := sum + array.get(arr, i)
    sum/length
    
arr_daily_closes = get_daily_closes(sec, lookback)
nday_avg = get_arr_avg(arr_daily_closes)
plot(nday_avg, color=color.red)
```

This will only work as intended if the chart's timeframe is set to Daily. Otherwise, it will plot the 10-bar moving average, and not 10-day moving average.

I also don't understand why I need to call `array.clear()` and `sum := 0` within those functions. It seems as though those variables should be created only each time I call the function... but I suppose that's a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions, both custom and built in can be used within the context of a security call.

```
sec = security("SPY", "D", sma(close, 10))
```

If you require the values in an array for another purpose you can do this :

```
var int lookback = 10

daily_close_ts = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", time_close)

var int min_in_ms = 60000

last_bar_ts = daily_close_ts - timeframe.multiplier * min_in_ms

var float[] daily_closes = array.new_float(lookback)

if barstate.isconfirmed and timeframe.isintraday and time == last_bar_ts
    array.unshift(daily_closes, close)
    array.pop(daily_closes)
    
l = label.new(x = bar_index, y = close, style = label.style_label_left, text = tostring(daily_closes))
label.delete(l[1])

daily_sma = array.avg(daily_closes)
plot(daily_sma)
```

You need to keep in mind though, that depending on your intraday timeframe and the length of lookback, it may exceed the number of daily values that are available. We can only access those values that exist within the historical range of the chart's timeframe. If the lookback exceeds what is available, you'll end up with an array that is partially still populated with `na` values.

Alternatively you can also approach it this way, however it will only obtain the day's close on the first bar of the next new day, rather than on the closing of the last intraday bar of the day.

```
var int lookback = 10

daily_close = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)


var float[] daily_closes = array.new_float(lookback)

if change(time("D")) != 0
    array.unshift(daily_closes, daily_close)
    array.pop(daily_closes)

l = label.new(x = bar_index, y = close, style = label.style_label_left, text = tostring(daily_closes))
label.delete(l[1])

daily_sma = array.avg(daily_closes)
plot(daily_sma)
```

If you declare your array or variable with the var keyword then it isn't reinitialized each bar, but maintains it's state from the previous bar. Since your functions will be called every bar, on the first bar they are created in the scope of the function and still exist within that scope when the function is called on subsequent bars. If you do want them to be reset each bar execution then you just declare them without the var keyword.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, truly appreciated! I'm a bit confused about the timeframe.multiplier calculation -- will this code only work if the chart's timeframe is minutes? I'm assuming I'll need different calcs for timeframe.isseconds, timeframe.isminutes, timeframe.isdays. If I understand things correctly, if it's days and multiplier is >1, I'll be forced to skip over some days.

Comment: Also, I'm confused by how array.pop(arr) works here. Wouldn't we want to only pop once we've unshifted `lookback` times?

Comment: Alos, this appears to only collect 1 value into the array. At each bar, I'd like the array to contain the close values for the previous 10 days. I can probably figure it out, but it'd be nice to see the "right" way to do this.

Comment: If you are trying to obtain daily values, then if your chart is 1D, then you don't need this, you can just the normal close time series variables and the historical operator close[1], etc. You can't obtain Daily values reliably if the TF is higher. Which leaves only intraday. But you are correct, for seconds timeframes you would need a slightly different calc using ms_in_a_second instead.

Comment: The array is initialized with the var keyword, with the size of the lookback. Initially it is "empty" and only contains na values. After each daily close we're adding the close to the beginning of the array, and removing using pop the last element. So there will always be lookback number of values in the array. Early in the historical range of the chart, the array will be mostly na values until 10 daily closes have occurred. You can't obtain daily values further back than what is available on the chart.

Comment: You won't be able to access 10 daily closes from the seconds charts anyway. The minimum timeframe with sufficient history would be the 1 min chart if you are on a premium account.

Comment: I tried the code and it isn't working -- it only plots a single point for the very last bar. I think for unconfirmed bars, the `time` is offset by some amount so that it never matches with `last_bar_ts`.

Comment: Sorry, the first only works on crypto markets for some reason, I've added another alternative